# Fast tapping on soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, listener

I'm using TextWatcher to prevent users to insert double spaces. the following is part of my code.

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        final String a = s.toString();
            final String b = s.toString().replace("  ", " ");


            if (a.length()>b.length()){
                int pos = name.getSelectionStart();
                name.setText(b);
                name.setSelection(pos-1);
            }}
```

The code works fine if one simple taps slowly. Anyway, the problems arise when you tap quite fast, then it begins deleting the characters just before the first space.

Do you have any idea why this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: In this case I would recommend to let the user type as many spaces as he want and after its done maybe in `onClick(..)` of a button you validate the text and replace spaces afterwards...

Comment: I tried your solution. It is working fine.